# What are the syntax changes from the shell script to the cshell script?

Tags: shell, sh, csh

I just came to know that `.sh` files don't use `set` and spaces around `=` are not allowed, while this is allowed in a `.csh` file.

Is there some place that you can point me to where I can find all these minor differences?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The documentation?

Csh and sh may look similar, but they are different languages. Just like C++ and Java have some similar constructs, but are different languages.

It is fairly common knowledge that [Csh programming is considered harmful](http://www.faqs.org/faqs/unix-faq/shell/csh-whynot/) for a variety of reasons.

(sh does use set but for different purposes)

Answer (score 1):

you can also take a look at [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_command_shells) for comparison between shells